# WebHook Listener in C# WPF

Tags: c#, webhooks

i need help to make a method to listen webhook in C# WPF.

Every time thh webhook recive a post/get I want add on a list to save a file.

Comment: That's not really how this site works. You write some code, debug it, run into an issue. You ask a detailed question accompanied by a [mcve], and people respond with answers, often including more code

Comment: Ok, I have a program running a LInux and have a webhook( requestcatcher for tests)
I need catcher the response of this in my application on WPF.